# How to calculate diff between previous rows and new rows for different columns

Tags: python, pandas, diff

I have a df as follows

```
index open close
       10  12
       15  16
       20   19
```

To find diff between previous row of one column, we can use

`df['diff] = df['close'].diff()`

But i want to find diff between current open and previous close. How can i do it?

```
index open close diff_new_open_prev_close
       10  12.    Nan
       15  16.    3
       20   19.   4

diff = current rows open - prev rows close
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html).

```
df['prev_close'] = df['close'].shift()
df['diff_new_open_prev_close'] =  df['open'] - df['prev_close']
print(df)

# Or 
df['diff_new_open_prev_close'] = df['open'].subtract(df['close'].shift())
```

Output:

```
   open  close  prev_close  diff_new_open_prev_close
0    10     12         NaN                       NaN
1    15     16        12.0                       3.0
2    20     19        16.0                       4.0
```